# Can I still receive money from AdMob if I don't own a company?

Tags: iphone, android, admob

I created an AdMob account to add a banner in my application, and I saw something *intriguing*: It asks for my Company name to send me money.

What happens if I just want some extra money and I don't plan a life living from my android apps? Am I screwed?

PS: My situation is about an android application, but of course it can be iphone related and so.

Comment: I would imagine this is off topic.  Still, an interesting question.  I would imagine that field is just so that they have a name for their records, but I don't want to stand behind that suggestion (thus it's not written in the answer area).

Comment: And, if so, where does an off-topic question go? I thought about the android enthusiasts place, but it's not about UI or mobile problems, it's a problem any developer willing to monetize would face. It's a pity people wants this question closed :/

Comment: Meh, fair enough, I can't think of a better place for it.  (Besides, I still think it's a good question, whether or not it's on topic).

Comment: What did AdMob say when you asked them?

Comment: No answer, probably until Monday

Comment: Ok, so closed as off. Well, whatever. I still think that, despite it hasn't got a single line of code, it is strongly related to software development.

Comment: +1 for sharing problem , @Korcholis i am making account on Admob for releasing my app , but do i need to give my bank account etc when i go to withdraw the money ? because its not showing me any option where i put my account for transfer etc but i also didnt release my app yet

Comment: You should put your bank account inside Account>Payments>Payments Settings, otherwise they have no way to pay you, and thus will retain any amount until you add the bank account AND confirm it (they tell you how, it's simple). In my case, I also had to add and confirm my address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to own a company.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what goes on the Company name?

Comment: Anything you wish. Perhaps the name of a future company? Or just write your real name.

Comment: If it isn't in a company's name, it is in yours.  Your name can be used for business.

Comment: What about Local Tax ID?

Comment: Local Tax ID is optional